# Tridion content Publications are not expanding

Tags: 2013-sp1, search

When I try to open a SDL Tridion content Publication I get the error below and the tree is not expanding.

I am getting this error every 10 sec in the event viewer. I have also checked that a domain user is already added to the SDLSearchUsers.

Where else I need to check this user that this is a correct user?

Note: We are using SDL Tridion 2013 SP1.

> Unable to index item: tcm:229-2211391. Sending a request to the Search Engine at http://localhost:8983/tridion failed with the following response: The connection can not be authenticated.
>
> Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Search.Indexing
>
> Errorcode: 865
>
> User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

**I am getting the following error as well.**

> A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_PUBLICATIONS_GETLISTDATA".
>   Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>   The wait operation timed out
>
> Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService
>   Errorcode: 831
>   User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Comment: Can you try by adding the MTS User in the SDLSearchUsers group and also ensure that MTS User and NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM have write access to the %Tridion_Home% directory (for sake of verification at least).

Comment: tcm:229-2211391 note the item id! Wouldn't rule out that the search issue is unrelated...

Comment: Updated my answer to include approach to resolve database timeout errors.

Answer (score 2):

If the issue is with the permission then you can easily identify that issue:

Browse url: `http://<CM Server>:8983` and provide the user name / pwd configured for search, if you are able to login and see all the configuration then it is not permission issue.

If it is not the permission issue then try to run powershell command to re-index the items: Sync-TcmSearchIndex (Reference: [Powershell to reindex](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2013&lang=en-US#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2013&lang=en-US&action=search&query=reindexing&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1371800397735&currentQuery=reindexing&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDoctask_CD6B11B846164C18ABB0FE2625785E21&query=reindexing&scope=&filename=ReindexingSearch.xml&docid=task_CD6B11B846164C18ABB0FE2625785E21&inner_id=&tid=fb0a83ab-ed09-458d-af63-797dadbc63fa&addHistory=true&resource=))

**For the database timeout error:**
Please get the `tables used by the procedure re-indexed.` We had similar issue when creating component corresponding schema dropdown was not getting populated and we were getting timeout errors.

Comment: I tried to check the permission issue and it seems fine. Don't have the access to run powershell so cannot do indexing. Can we do indexing  from database side ?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting when running powershell? Are you running powershell on CM server?

Answer (score 0):

I have come across same issue and this can also happen due to Tridion CM database user properties got messed up.

### How to Fix?

- Logon to the SQL Server with "Tridion DB User"
- Open the user properties of the CM database
- Click on "Membership" and select the "db_owner" (Tick Mark)
- Click "Ok"
- Restart the Tridion DB services

Now verify, issue will get resolved.